# how to set a timeout for redis-cli command?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cli

I have a health check I'm trying to use that executes the redis-cli command from the redis servers to the redis-sentinels remotely.

```
redis-cli -h 10.10.10.10 -p 26379 SENTINEL MASTER testing
```

There is a logic that sorts out whether there is a quorum and it all works fine unless a sentinel's network interface is unavailable. The redis-cli command hangs indefinitely in this case and the health check fails even though there are two healthy sentinels with a quorum.

I can't seem to find a way to set a timeout for the redis-cli on the client side to prevent it from hanging. Is there a way with redis-cli to do this or will I have to go outside the command to ensure it doesn't hang indefinitely?

Comment: I need to do the same thing in PowerShell. I'd prefer not to have to write a wrapper function, but I can't find a built-in timeout option in Redis.

Answer (score 18):

I decided to use the `timeout` command to wrap the redis-cli command. It seems to work very well for my purposes!

```
timeout 3 redis-cli -h 10.10.10.10 -p 26379 SENTINEL MASTER testing
```